# How to uri encode a large text file with python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large text file that i want to be uri argument encoded. I researched a bit and came up with this:

```
import urllib
f=open('text.txt','r').read()
n= open('encodeTest.txt','w')
new=urllib.quote_plus(f) 
n.write(new)
```

I get this error whenever I run it:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'quote_plus'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3 removed quote_plus from urllib's module. You need to import urllib.parse and go from there. However, there will be issues as you encode larger files so it probably makes sense to encode 1024 bytes at a time.

```
import urllib.parse
f=open('text.txt','r').read()
f.close()
n= open('encodeTest.txt','w')
for x in range(0, len(f), 1024):
    buf = f[x:x+1024]
    n.write(urllib.parse.quote_plus(buf))
n.close()
```

Comment: What kind of issues are you talking about? I did end up encoding a large text file and it seemed to work fine, but since this is my first time doing this maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You want [urllib.parse.unquote_plus](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus). But even this wouldn't work if you're encoding a large file since the [max URL length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) is ~2000 chars